# Removing Ubuntu 12.04 from external harddrive

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I had Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my 1Tb hard drive, but I somehow corrupted GNome and now it just tells me to reinstall it. I cant uninstall it because I see no "Ubuntu" directory on my hard drive.

Edit1: It has data on it that is valuable and I cannot format it. Its not taking up any space some how, but I would like to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 again.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if this is an external harddrive with nothing on it except Ubuntu you would just need to format the entire drive. Attach it to your computer, right click the icon in launcher, and select format.

If Ubuntu is on one partition and you have data on another partition, then use gparted to format the correct partition.

If this doesn't answer your question please edit your question to include more detail.

Comment: Edited. I was thinking of formatting but I really cant.

Comment: @gamercat Then just mount it as a normal external drive and copy of your data and then format. Otherwise your question is: "How to fix Ubuntu after corrupting Gnome?". In that case ask a new question and add some detail about how you corrupted Gnome.

Comment: If the external hard drive is formatted `ext4` you will need to use a Live/DC/USB/DVD to boot Ubuntu and then plugin the drive. If the data is in FAT32 or NTFS partition, you can boot Windows and plug in the drive and copy the data from it.